# automapper conversion from decimal to bool if not null

Tags: c#, automapper-4

I am trying to convert from bool value to decimal i automapper. It works fine if i dont check for null values .But i want to check for null values and if the value is null ,let the value be null i destination else convert to decimal.Below is the ode i tied but i am getting a error.

```
  cfg.CreateMap<sourcemodel, destinatiomodel>()    
     .ForMember(dest =>  dest.WorkhoursPerWeek != null ? 
                Convert.ToDecimal(dest.WorkhoursPerWeek) : null, 
                opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.cstu_WorkHoursPerWeek));
```

Comment: Just make your dest.WorkhoursPerWeek as Nullable<decimal> or decimal?

Comment: Please show the properties you're trying to map. "I want to convert from bool to decimal" sounds really weird.

Comment: krillagar, Can you please look at the code

Answer (score 0):

You code doesn't make sense (mainly because it's invalid).  If you need to check the source property first, I'd suggest using `AfterMap()`

```
cfg.CreateMap<sourcemodel, destinatiomodel>()    
  .AfterMap((src, dest) =>  
    {
      dest = dest.WorkhoursPerWeek != null 
      ? Convert.ToDecimal(dest.WorkhoursPerWeek) 
      : src.cstu_WorkHoursPerWeek
    });
```

(Or this might not work, and if not, use BeforeMap() to map before and Ignore() the property).

Comment: I highly recommend when you communicate with other technical people (anywhere not just SO) that you be much more descriptive about a problem you face.  For example, what can I possible do with a `I am getting an error`?  I don't have an exception, nor code; you haven't presented me with any information to help you.

Comment: cfg.CreateMap<cstu_ApplicantExam, ApplicantExamModel>()


               
  .AfterMap((src, dest) =>
  {
      dest = dest.Score != null
      ? Convert.ToDecimal(dest.Score)
      : src.cstu_Score
    })  
                  
            .ForMember(dest => dest.ApplicantExamId, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.cstu_ApplicantExamId))
       
            .ReverseMap();

Comment: Cannot simply convert type decimal? to Model

Comment: probably need to change `dest =` to `dest.property =`.

Comment: @Erik..Did not work.Can you please test the code and send if you have time or else it is fine